# Click on web browser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to programatically click on WebBrowser1's web page.

I tried: `WebBrowser1.Document.Click()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to open a URL? You'd try `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.help-info.de")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot click the document itself, however you can access the body via [**`WebBrowser.Document.Body`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body(v=vs.110).aspx) and then call [**`InvokeMember()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5b41b0d(v=vs.110).aspx) on that:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: @SesManijak : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, i need lots of luck xD